# maven version plugin NPE

Tags: maven, plugins, command, version

Hi I'm trying to execute

```
mvn  versions:set -DgroupId=a304-b5c1d9177065 -DnewVersion=2.2.2
```

for my project  with this pom.xml

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>mul-project-template-artifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>  
<packaging>mule-application</packaging>
<name>mul-project-template</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <app.runtime>4.3.0-20210119</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.4.2</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
</properties>
```

mvn clean install

is working with build success

but

```
mvn  versions:set -DgroupId=a304-b5c1d9177065 -DnewVersion=2.2.2
```

returns

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:set (default-cli) on project logger-connector-artifact: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:set failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Working with latest version also shows same exception

```
 ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set (default-cli) on project logger-connector-artifact: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set failed.: NullPointerException -> –
```

I also have this warning

```
[WARNING] 'groupId' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ ${groupId}:logger-connector-artifact:1.0.0, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ine_logger-connector_development/pom.xml, line 5, column 11 [WARNING] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
```

Comment: Please use the most recent version of the versions-maven-plugin....  https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

Comment: I already used the latest version and it didn't work, some forums advised to use version 2.1 that could resolve the problem
But with 2.1 version also, the problem is not solved

Comment: First based on the post you don't use the recent version: `n-plugin:2.1:set f` That's extreme old version... the most recent version is 2.8.1...furthermore remove the `<groupId>${groupId}</groupId>` ...

Comment: I updated the latest version and I'm getting
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set (default-cli) on project logger-connector-artifact: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:set failed.: NullPointerException ->

Comment: also note that I'm using groupId as parameter and fixed it under properties like described in the post
and I'm also getting this message

ING] 'groupId' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ ${groupId}:logger-connector-artifact:1.0.0, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ine_logger-connector_development/pom.xml, line 5, column 11
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

Comment: Please make a github or alike example project...

Comment: Can you run with `-e -X` and post the output?

Comment: As I mentioned remove the `<groupId>${groupId}</groupId>` replace with a literal value...because usually it does not make sense to use a property...

Comment: I can't, it is too complicated to explain, but I should use a variable there

Comment: First try to remove the variable because it's not supported by Maven itself so try first without ...based on the WARNING you get... See if that is working with versions-maven-plugin.

Comment: When I remove variable it is working,
But I need this variable, and with this variable mvn clean install works without problems
why mvn versions:set is causing this NPE ?

Comment: That's what I expected. So you have to reconsider the usage of the variable because it does not make sense...If you like to know what the NPE occurs please take a look into the source code https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin ...